# Navigation Drawer closing bug

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created a side navigation when open and close it by clicking on the icon of all good. When the side navigation and try to close it by clicking on its edge application fails. What's the problem? Here is my code:

```
package com.mdev.learnit;

import com.mdev.learnit.helpprogramms.Calculator;
import com.mdev.learnit.settings.SettingsActivity;
import com.mdev.learnit.theory.AlgebraTheoryActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    final int DIALOG_EXIT = 1;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_names);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);


        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               R.layout.drawer_text, mPlanetTitles));


        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  
                mDrawerLayout,        
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
       if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
           return true;
       }
       switch(item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.theory_menu:
           intent.setClass(StartActivity.this, AlgebraTheoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           return true;
       case R.id.settings_menu:
           intent.setClass(StartActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           return true;
       case R.id.calculator_menu:
           intent.setClass(StartActivity.this, Calculator.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           return true;
       default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }



    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
      }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    public void onclick(View v) {
          showDialog(DIALOG_EXIT);
        }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
          if (id == DIALOG_EXIT) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            adb.setTitle(R.string.exit);
            adb.setMessage(R.string.really);
            adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            adb.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, myClickListener);
            adb.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, myClickListener);
            return adb.create();
          }
          return super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }

    OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          switch (which) {
          case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            finish();
            break;
          case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:          
                    dialog.cancel();
            break;
          }
        }
      };

      public void onBackPressed() {
          showDialog(DIALOG_EXIT);
        }    

}
```

Here is my log:

```
06-24 10:24:48.434: E/InputEventReceiver(373): Exception dispatching input event.
06-24 10:24:48.434: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isContentView(DrawerLayout.java:805)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:831)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1817)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2236)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1456)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2184)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4299)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4278)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4370)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
06-24 10:24:48.441: E/MessageQueue-JNI(373):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 10:24:48.441: D/AndroidRuntime(373): Shutting down VM
06-24 10:24:48.441: W/dalvikvm(373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f3e888)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isContentView(DrawerLayout.java:805)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:831)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1817)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2236)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1456)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2184)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4299)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4278)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4370)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
06-24 10:24:48.449: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Applications fails == it crashes? Post your logcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `FragmentLayout with layout_width/layout_height = match_parent property` in your main layout. If you don't need this, don't use/call `FragmentLayout` in your activity. I know, this is not a good solution, but, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see .closeDrawer() being called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I found this solution and it may help future readers.

In case you do not want your drawer layout to cover the entire screen and still solve the issue check to see if you have any margins added to your Fragment Layout (in your layout xml).

If yes then remove those and this should solve it. This sounds weird but yes it does the trick. :)

Similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876945/drawerlayout-exception-dispatching-input-event).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android Doc about create an Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) you need to create `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` as root for your layout with two Child views : `FragmentLayout` and `ListView`

**because** `the XML order implies z-ordering and the drawer must be on top of the content.`

**If** you don't need to use `FragmentLayout` view ,you can make it's `visibility` is `gone`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**If** you need to create more than one `FragmentLayout` you can create `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` as first Child for `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` Root view

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_first"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_second"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_belo="@id/fragment_first" >

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```