# DrawerLayout - Exception dispatching input event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-library, drawerlayout

I recently started using the DrawerLayout in a new project about a week ago and it's all working fine. Apart from the odd times when swiping it in and out with my finger it'll crash.

If I use the ActionBar Up/Home MenuItem though, it'll work fine every time.

In LogCat i get two stacktraces that both seem to point to internal android places, so I don't quite know what to do to solve this.

I just tried creating a new application to see if it was something I was doing before that was causing this, but it happened in the new application too.

I created the new application with the Master/Detail Flow template in the "New Android Application" window, left everything as defaults and just changed activity_item_list.xml to have this inside it:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:name="com.navdrawertest.ItemListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The DrawerLayout shows and I can still drag it from the edge of the screen, but it still crashes in this test app.

Here are the stacktraces I see after dragging it with my finger:

```
07-26 09:29:45.574: E/InputEventReceiver(19085): Exception dispatching input event.
07-26 09:29:45.574: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isContentView(DrawerLayout.java:840)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:866)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1852)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-26 09:29:45.584: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19085):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 09:29:45.584: D/AndroidRuntime(19085): Shutting down VM
07-26 09:29:45.584: W/dalvikvm(19085): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cbb700)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isContentView(DrawerLayout.java:840)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:866)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1852)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-26 09:29:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(19085):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Edit: 10 days in and still can't figure this out, can I at least get confirmation that this isn't just me getting this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have also got this error message but at first I couldn't find out what caused it.
After doing some tests I actually found out that **removing all margins** on the View (in your example the fragment) seems to remove the problem.

So in your case it would be:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:name="com.navdrawertest.ItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

and you can set margins on all the views inside this fragment instead (but I haven't tested it).
Hope it helps someone. It seems that this problem is not so common.

Comment: This felt like an strange solution, but it actually helped me, thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped, not much documentation on this one so I guess it's a rather new "bug" (it sounds as a bug at least).

Comment: After having a play around with the example that Android Studio creates. It's working perfectly fine and it doesn't have any margins on the fragments. So this must be what was originally causing my problem too. So I'll set this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think I've managed to fix this by creating my own copies of the files I needed from the support library source code and catching the null View in `isContentView()`.

The files I needed from the source were:

- ActionBarDrawerToggle.java
- ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java
- DrawerLayout.java

I put them in their own package in my project and renamed `DrawerLayout` to `FixedDrawerLayout`. (So I can easily tell which copy of the DrawerLayout I'm using)

I then changed `isContentView()` to:

```
boolean isContentView(View child) {
    if(child == null){
        return false;
    }
    return ((LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).gravity == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
}
```

After swapping all references to the `DrawerLayout` in my `Activity` to `FixedDrawerLayout` it seems to have fixed it.

Not sure if there is anything that can happen by just returning `false` in `isContentView()`, but it doesn't crash anymore and it's still usable even when `child` is null.

Comment: Just a little hint. You do not need to copy any files. As isContentView is package private, you only need to subclass DrawerLayout in a package structure equivalent to the original one. You end up with a class android.support.v4.widget.RepairedDrawerLayout that override the method, returning false if the child is null.
BTW: You can also call closeAllDrawers() here to close the navigation drawer if the child is null.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! I wasn't aware that I could subclass like that.

Comment: @user1050133 subclassing DrawerLayout is not a good idea because the package structure for the app Project (where you want this fixed) is not going to be the package structure implied by android.support.v4.widget.RepairedDrawerLayout.  That means you will not be able to subclass it in your project unless you change your whole project structure to match the package structure.  Mike's solution is the path of least resistance. But I like your idea of adding closeAllDrawers() into the null check for isContentView().

Comment: Awesome! This is the only valid solution for this bug. A tried others with no results. Great research and solution, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, but I'm having trouble with the implementation: How do you instantiate the FixedDrawerLayout? This downcasting does not work for me:
(FixedDrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

Comment: Have you changed the references to DrawerLayout in your layout xml to the FixedDrawerLayout?

Comment: You are a life saver :)

Answer (score 4):

Building on Mike's answer and user1050133's comment:

1) Create the package `android.support.v4.widget` in your app

2) Add a new file called `FixedDrawerLayout` with the following content:

```
public class FixedDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    public FixedDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FixedDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    boolean isContentView(View child) {
        if (child == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return ((LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).gravity == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
    }
}
```

3) Replace all uses of DrawerLayout in xml with FixedDrawerLayout

Answer (score 2):

I faced with similar problem.

I put a fake onclick mathod for fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f1f2f6"
    android:onClick="fragmentClick"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

I put the onclick method in activity java code just for fake.

```
public void fragmentClick(View v){
    Log.i("fragmentClick", "fragmentClick");
    return;
}
```

Problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while using the navigation drawer, and I have solved the problem simply by removing the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` from the root layout of the fragment.