# NullPointerException when pressing on included layout part

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Howzit,

I have a static header that is being included in my layout that contains a listview.  The functionality works great, however whenever I click on the job it throws a NullPointerException (I want nothing to happen)

Not to sure why this is happening.

Container.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <include android:id="@+id/headerItem"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="76dip"
           android:background="@color/standard_background"
           layout="@layout/List_Item"/>

  <ListView
      android:id="@id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/headerItem"
      android:background="@color/standard_background" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

List_Item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dip"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="8dp">
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

           ...a couple of textviews
    </LinearLayout>   
           ...a single textview
   </LinearLayout>
```

I have attempted to set it to disabled, not focusable as well as disabled the click and long click.  Not sure what else to try.

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
 java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isContentView(DrawerLayout.java:840)
      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:866)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1859)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
      at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:255)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
shutting down VM
d=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41889ba8)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
rocess: co.za.fieldservice.tcm, PID: 21008
ava.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isContentView(DrawerLayout.java:840)
      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:866)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1859)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
      at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:255)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**DrawerLayout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >

      <ListView android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
          android:divider="@color/light_gray"
          android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
          android:background="@color/standard_background"/>

    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  <!-- The main content view -->
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_frame"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_content_padding"
      />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can share with us?

Comment: Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from your second `LinearLayout` in `List_Item.xml`

Comment: @SK9 stacktrace added

Comment: @MD does one only set that on the root element??  attempting this now.

Comment: @Johan ya, only one main contain this

Comment: @MD even with it removed, it still throws the same exception.

Comment: @Johan ya i know that. error is coming from different but it's just your correction

Comment: It has something to do with your `DrawerLayout`. If possible, post your code+layout related to it.

Comment: I have fixed the issues I was having, it was to do with the drawer layout, the drawers width was said to match parent and thus overlaying the other content.  Changing the width to the same as the drawerlist fixed everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the drawer layout.

The drawers width was set to `match_parent`, thus making it overlay some other views and causing an exception to occur when pressing anywhere (anywhere in the whitespace).

When I changed the width to be the same value as the value of the left margin of my `content_frame` everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new id in xml:

```
<include android:id="@+id/headerItem" // remove it 
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="76dip"
           android:background="@color/standard_background"
           layout="@layout/List_Item"/>
```

then just find the layout by id in your activity like below.

```
layout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.headerItem);
```

It should be fix NPE.

Comment: I removed it, and now the header isn't being included anymore.

Comment: I set the id in the layout I am including, but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

match_parent does the trick but then it looses the essence of Drawer Layout. :(

The issue above was indeed because of the margins added to the Frame Layout which you are using for your Fragments. This is strange but true.

Try removing the margins and your layout will look as,

```
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/content_frame"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876945/drawerlayout-exception-dispatching-input-event).

Let know if this helps. :)